# Response 400 while using Requests package in Django

Tags: django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.7

I want to **scrape** Myntra using Django Framework but when I put my code in Django project I get 400 error. The same code runs without error when I run it on the same file even in Django. Means calling the MyntraScraperClass in MyntraScraper.py file.

Here is my project directory

```
BackendController
    -MyntraScraper.py
myDjangoApp
    -views.py
```

Inside views.py, there is a function where I am calling my MyntraScraperClass

```
def tst(request):
    ------------
```

The same code that is MyntraScraperClass runs error free when I call it on

```
BackendController
    -MyntraScraper.py
```

Here is my code:

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, ssl
import certifi
import urllib3

class MyntraScraperClass:

    def __init__(self,url):
        self.url=url


    def myntra(self):
        mt={}

        http = urllib3.PoolManager(
                cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
                ca_certs=certifi.where())

        if (not os.environ.get('PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY', '') and getattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context', None)):
            ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

        proxy = {'http': '-------'}

        headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}
        for x in range(0,5):
            print(x)
            try:
                s = requests.Session()
                res = s.get(self.url, headers=headers, verify=True, proxies=proxy)
                print(res)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
                print(soup)
                if "Access Denied" in soup.title:
                    continue
                break
            except requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
                continue
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                mt['error']=e


        script = None
        for s in soup.find_all("script"):
            if 'pdpData' in s.text:
                script = s.get_text(strip=True)
                break
            else:
                continue

        mt['data'] =json.loads(script[script.index('{'):])
        return mt
```

I am calling MyntraScraperClass in my Django Views from BackendController directory.

```
def tst(request):
    url = request.GET.get('url')
    from BackendController.MyntraScraper import  MyntraScraperClass
    
    obj1 = MyntraScraperClass(url)
    kk = obj1.myntra()
    print(kk)
    return JsonResponse(kk)
```

The response is

```
<Response [400]>
```

I am getting this in soup

```
<html><head>
<title>Invalid URL</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Invalid URL</h1>
The requested URL "[no URL]", is invalid.<p>
Reference #9.6b722c31.1596891375.7bfc4ae
</p></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you post a myntra url you are looking to scrape?

Comment: this url- https://www.myntra.com/sports-shoes/puma/puma-men-blue-hybrid-fuego-running-shoes/11203218/buy

and for all product showing the same error.

Comment: What does `    url = request.GET.get('url')` actually return to you where this isn't working? How are you specifying it? It looks like you're trying to retrieve the `url` from the query parameters and I strongly suspect the URL isn't being properly encoded before reaching Django and thus is causing other issues once passed to Requests

Answer (score 1):

You should try to solve your problem using https://scrapy.org/, here are the docs https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/

Comment: What makes you suggest this ? Scrapy is not the most user friendly of frameworks and requires a knowledge of OOP. It's also best used for intermediate to large data sets. If the data is simple and not making too many requests, requests and beautifulsoup are just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}

class MyntraScraperClass:

    def __init__(self,url):
        self.url=url
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def myntra(self):
        res = self.session.get(self.url, headers=headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

        script = None

        for s in soup.find_all("script"):
            if 'pdpData' in s.text:
                script = s.get_text(strip=True)
                break
        
        try:
            return json.loads(script[script.index('{'):])
        except: 
            return None

scraperClass = MyntraScraperClass("https://www.myntra.com/sports-shoes/puma/puma-men-blue-hybrid-fuego-running-shoes/11203218/buy")
data = scraperClass.myntra()
print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'pdpData': {'id': 11203218, 'name': 'Puma Men Blue Hybrid Fuego Running Shoes', 'mrp': 6499, 'manufacturer': 'SSIPL RETAIL LIMITED, KUNDLI,75, SERSA ROAD, 131028 SONEPAT', 'countryOfOrigin': 'India', 'colours': None, 'baseColour': 'Blue', 'brand': {'uidx': '', 'name': 'Puma', 'image': '', 'bio': ''}, 'media': {'videos': [], 'albums': [{'name': 'default', 'images': [{'src': 'http://assets.myntassets.com/h_($height),q_($qualityPercentage),w_($width)/v1/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/0c15e03c-863b-4a4a-9bb7-709a733fd4821576816965952-1.jpg', 'secureSrc': 'https://assets.myntassets.com/h_($height),q_($qualityPercentage),w_($width)/v1/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/0c15e03c-863b-4a4a-9bb7-709a733fd4821576816965952-1.jpg', 'host': None, 'imageURL': 'http://assets.myntassets.com/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/0c15e03c-863b-4a4a-9bb7-709a733fd4821576816965952-1.jpg', 'annotation': []}, {'src': 'http://assets.myntassets.com/h_($height),q_($qualityPercentage),w_($width)/v1/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/69bfa4e0-1ac4-4adf-b84e-4815ff60e8831576816966007-2.jpg', 'secureSrc': 'https://assets.myntassets.com/h_($height),q_($qualityPercentage),w_($width)/v1/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/69bfa4e0-1ac4-4adf-b84e-4815ff60e8831576816966007-2.jpg', 'host': None, 'imageURL': 'http://assets.myntassets.com/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/69bfa4e0-1ac4-4adf-b84e-4815ff60e8831576816966007-2.jpg', 'annotation': []}, {'src': 'http://assets.myntassets.com/h_($height),q_($qualityPercentage),w_($width)/v1/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/d2fd0ca0-1643-43ae-a0fc-fb1309580e151576816966049-3.jpg', 'secureSrc': 'https://assets.myntassets.com/h_($height),q_($qualityPercentage),w_($width)/v1/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/d2fd0ca0-1643-43ae-a0fc-fb1309580e151576816966049-3.jpg', 'host': None, 'imageURL': 'http://assets.myntassets.com/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/d2fd0ca0-1643-43ae-a0fc-fb1309580e151576816966049-3.jpg', 'annotation': []}, {'src': 'http://assets.myntassets.com/h_($height),q_($qualityPercentage),w_($width)/v1/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/0edae428-b9c0-4755-9127-0961d872b78a1576816966095-4.jpg', 'secureSrc': 'https://assets.myntassets.com/h_($height),q_($qualityPercentage),w_($width)/v1/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/0edae428-b9c0-4755-9127-0961d872b78a1576816966095-4.jpg', 'host': None, 'imageURL': 'http://assets.myntassets.com/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/0edae428-b9c0-4755-9127-0961d872b78a1576816966095-4.jpg', 'annotation': []}, {'src': 'http://assets.myntassets.com/h_($height),q_($qualityPercentage),w_($width)/v1/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/c59c7677-2bbd-4dbe-9b02-7c321c29cb701576816966142-5.jpg', 'secureSrc': 'https://assets.myntassets.com/h_($height),q_($qualityPercentage),w_($width)/v1/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/c59c7677-2bbd-4dbe-9b02-7c321c29cb701576816966142-5.jpg', 'host': None, 'imageURL': 'http://assets.myntassets.com/assets/images/productimage/2019/12/20/c59c7677-2bbd-4dbe-9b02-7c321c29cb701576816966142-5.jpg', 'annotation': []}]}, {'name': 'animatedImage', 'images': []}]}, 'sbpEnabled': False, 'sizechart': {'sizeChartUrl': None, 'sizeRepresentationUrl': 'http://assets.myntassets.com/assets/images/sizechart/2016/12/12/11481538267795-footwear.png'}, 'sizeRecoLazy': {'actionType': 'lazy', 'action': '/product/11203218/size/recommendation', 'sizeProfileAction': '/user/size-profiles?gender=male&articleType=Sports%20Shoes'}, 'analytics': {'articleType': 'Sports Shoes', 'subCategory': 'Shoes', 'masterCategory': 'Footwear', 'gender': 'Men', 'brand': 'Puma', 'colourHexCode': None}, 'crossLinks': [{'title': 'More Sports Shoes by Puma', 'url': 'sports-shoes?f=Brand:Puma::Gender:men'}, {'title': 'More Blue Sports Shoes', 'url': 'sports-shoes?f=Color:Blue_0074D9::Gender:men'}, {'title': 'More Sports Shoes', 'url': 'sports-shoes?f=Gender:men'}], 'relatedStyles': None, 'disclaimerTitle': '', 'productDetails': [{'type': None, 'content': None, 'title': 'Product Details', 'description': "<b>FEATURES + BENEFITS</b><br>HYBRID: PUMA's combination of two of its best technologies: IGNITE foam and NRGY beads<br>IGNITE: PUMA's foam midsole and branded heel cage supports and stabilises by locking the heel onto the platform<br>NRGY: PUMA's foam midsole offers superior cushion from heel to toe so you can power through your run<br>Heel-to-toe drop: 12mm<br><br><b>Product Design Details</b><ul><li>A pair of blue &amp; brown running sports shoes, has regular styling, lace-up detail</li><li>Low boot silhouette</li><li>Lightweight synthetic upper</li><li>Overlays to secure the heel</li><li>Classic tongue</li><li>Lace-up closure</li><li>Rubber outsole for traction and durability</li><li>PUMA Wordmark at the tongue</li><li>PUMA Cat Logo at heel</li><li>Warranty: 3 months</li><li>Warranty provided by brand/manufacturer</li></ul><br><b>PRODUCT STORY</b><br>Change the name of the game with the HYBRID Fuego running sneakers. This bold colour-blocked shoe pairs a HYBRID foam midsole and a grippy rubber outsole for the ultimate in comfort and stability while still maintaining a stylish edge."}, {'type': None, 'content': None, 'title': 'MATERIAL & CARE', 'description': 'Textile<br>Wipe with a clean, dry cloth to remove dust'}], 'preOrder': None, 'sizeChartDisclaimerText': '', 'tags': None, 'articleAttributes': {'Ankle Height': 'Regular', 'Arch Type': 'Medium', 'Cleats': 'No Cleats', 'Cushioning': 'Medium', 'Distance': 'Medium', 'Fastening': 'Lace-Ups', 'Material': 'Textile', 'Outsole Type': 'Marking', 'Pronation for Running Shoes': 'Neutral', 'Running Type': 'Road Running', 'Sole Material': 'Rubber', 'Sport': 'Running', 'Surface Type': 'Outdoor', 'Technology': 'NA', 'Warranty': '3 months'}, 'systemAttributes': [], 'ratings': None, 'urgency': [{'value': '0', 'type': 'PURCHASED', 'ptile': 0}, {'value': '0', 'type': 'CART', 'ptile': 0}, {'value': '0', 'type': 'WISHLIST', 'ptile': 0}, {'value': '0', 'type': 'PDP', 'ptile': 0}], 'catalogAttributes': {'catalogDate': '1576751286000', 'season': 'summer', 'year': '2020'}, 'productContentGroupEntries': [{'title': '', 'type': 'DETAILS', 'attributes': [{'attributeName': 'Product Details', 'attributeType': 'STRING', 'value': "<b>FEATURES + BENEFITS</b><br>HYBRID: PUMA's combination of two of its best technologies: IGNITE foam and NRGY beads<br>IGNITE: PUMA's foam midsole and branded heel cage supports and stabilises by locking the heel onto the platform<br>NRGY: PUMA's foam midsole offers superior cushion from heel to toe so you can power through your run<br>Heel-to-toe drop: 12mm<br><br><b>Product Design Details</b><ul><li>A pair of blue &amp; brown running sports shoes, has regular styling, lace-up detail</li><li>Low boot silhouette</li><li>Lightweight synthetic upper</li><li>Overlays to secure the heel</li><li>Classic tongue</li><li>Lace-up closure</li><li>Rubber outsole for traction and durability</li><li>PUMA Wordmark at the tongue</li><li>PUMA Cat Logo at heel</li><li>Warranty: 3 months</li><li>Warranty provided by brand/manufacturer</li></ul><br><b>PRODUCT STORY</b><br>Change the name of the game with the HYBRID Fuego running sneakers. This bold colour-blocked shoe pairs a HYBRID foam midsole and a grippy rubber outsole for the ultimate in comfort and stability while still maintaining a stylish edge."}, {'attributeName': 'Material & Care', 'attributeType': 'STRING', 'value': 'Textile<br>Wipe with a clean, dry cloth to remove dust'}, {'attributeName': 'Style Note', 'attributeType': 'STRING', 'value': "You'll look and feel super stylish in these trendsetting sports shoes by Puma.  Match this blue pair with track pants and a sleeveless sports T-shirt when heading out for a casual day with friends."}]}], 'shoppableLooks': None, 'descriptors': [{'title': 'description', 'description': "<b>FEATURES + BENEFITS</b><br>HYBRID: PUMA's combination of two of its best technologies: IGNITE foam and NRGY beads<br>IGNITE: PUMA's foam midsole and branded heel cage supports and stabilises by locking the heel onto the platform<br>NRGY: PUMA's foam midsole offers superior cushion from heel to toe so you can power through your run<br>Heel-to-toe drop: 12mm<br><br><b>Product Design Details</b><ul><li>A pair of blue &amp; brown running sports shoes, has regular styling, lace-up detail</li><li>Low boot silhouette</li><li>Lightweight synthetic upper</li><li>Overlays to secure the heel</li><li>Classic tongue</li><li>Lace-up closure</li><li>Rubber outsole for traction and durability</li><li>PUMA Wordmark at the tongue</li><li>PUMA Cat Logo at heel</li><li>Warranty: 3 months</li><li>Warranty provided by brand/manufacturer</li></ul><br><b>PRODUCT STORY</b><br>Change the name of the game with the HYBRID Fuego running sneakers. This bold colour-blocked shoe pairs a HYBRID foam midsole and a grippy rubber outsole for the ultimate in comfort and stability while still maintaining a stylish edge."}, {'title': 'style_note', 'description': "You'll look and feel super stylish in these trendsetting sports shoes by Puma.  Match this blue pair with track pants and a sleeveless sports T-shirt when heading out for a casual day with friends."}, {'title': 'materials_care_desc', 'description': 'Textile<br>Wipe with a clean, dry cloth to remove dust'}], 'flags': {'isExchangeable': True, 'isReturnable': True, 'openBoxPickupEnabled': True, 'tryAndBuyEnabled': True, 'isLarge': False, 'isHazmat': False, 'isFragile': False, 'isJewellery': False, 'outOfStock': False, 'codEnabled': True, 'globalStore': False, 'loyaltyPointsEnabled': False, 'emiEnabled': True, 'chatEnabled': False, 'measurementModeEnabled': False, 'sampleModeEnabled': False, 'disableBuyButton': False}, 'earlyBirdOffer': None, 'serviceability': {'launchDate': '', 'returnPeriod': 30, 'descriptors': ['Pay on delivery might be available', 'Easy 30 days returns and exchanges', 'Try & Buy might be available'], 'procurementTimeInDays': {'6206': 4}}, 'buyButtonSellerOrder': [{'skuId': 38724440, 'sellerPartnerId': 6206}, {'skuId': 38724442, 'sellerPartnerId': 6206}, {'skuId': 38724446, 'sellerPartnerId': 6206}, {'skuId': 38724450, 'sellerPartnerId': 6206}, {'skuId': 38724452, 'sellerPartnerId': 6206}, {'skuId': 38724444, 'sellerPartnerId': 6206}, {'skuId': 38724448, 'sellerPartnerId': 6206}], 'sellers': [{'sellerPartnerId': 6206, 'sellerName': 'Puma Sports India Pvt. Ltd.(NSCM)'}], 'sizes': [{'skuId': 38724440, 'styleId': 11203218, 'action': '/product/11203218/related/6?co=1', 'label': '6', 'available': True, 'sizeType': 'UK Size', 'originalStyle': True, 'measurements': [{'type': 'Body Measurement', 'name': 'To Fit Foot Length', 'value': '24.5', 'minValue': '24.5', 'maxValue': '24.5', 'unit': 'cm', 'displayText': '24.5cm'}], 'allSizesList': [{'scaleCode': 'uk_size', 'sizeValue': '6', 'size': 'UK Size', 'order': 1, 'prefix': 'UK'}, {'scaleCode': 'us_size', 'sizeValue': '7', 'size': 'US Size', 'order': 2, 'prefix': 'US'}, {'scaleCode': 'euro_size', 'sizeValue': '39', 'size': 'Euro Size', 'order': 3, 'prefix': 'EURO'}], 'sizeSellerData': [{'mrp': 6499, 'sellerPartnerId': 6206, 'availableCount': 10, 'sellableInventoryCount': 10, 'warehouses': ['106'], 'supplyType': 'ON_HAND', 'discountId': '11203218:23363948', 'discountedPrice': 2924}]}, {'skuId': 38724442, 'styleId': 11203218, 'action': '/product/11203218/related/7?co=1', 'label': '7', 'available': True, 'sizeType': 'UK Size', 'originalStyle': True, 'measurements': [{'type': 'Body Measurement', 'name': 'To Fit Foot Length', 'value': '25.4', 'minValue': '25.4', 'maxValue': '25.4', 'unit': 'cm', 'displayText': '25.4cm'}], 'allSizesList': [{'scaleCode': 'uk_size', 'sizeValue': '7', 'size': 'UK Size', 'order': 1, 'prefix': 'UK'}, {'scaleCode': 'us_size', 'sizeValue': '8', 'size': 'US Size', 'order': 2, 'prefix': 'US'}, {'scaleCode': 'euro_size', 'sizeValue': '40.5', 'size': 'Euro Size', 'order': 3, 'prefix': 'EURO'}], 'sizeSellerData': [{'mrp': 6499, 'sellerPartnerId': 6206, 'availableCount': 49, 'sellableInventoryCount': 49, 'warehouses': ['106'], 'supplyType': 'ON_HAND', 'discountId': '11203218:23363948', 'discountedPrice': 2924}]}, {'skuId': 38724444, 'styleId': 11203218, 'action': '/product/11203218/related/8?co=1', 'label': '8', 'available': True, 'sizeType': 'UK Size', 'originalStyle': True, 'measurements': [{'type': 'Body Measurement', 'name': 'To Fit Foot Length', 'value': '26.2', 'minValue': '26.2', 'maxValue': '26.2', 'unit': 'cm', 'displayText': '26.2cm'}], 'allSizesList': [{'scaleCode': 'uk_size', 'sizeValue': '8', 'size': 'UK Size', 'order': 1, 'prefix': 'UK'}, {'scaleCode': 'us_size', 'sizeValue': '9', 'size': 'US Size', 'order': 2, 'prefix': 'US'}, {'scaleCode': 'euro_size', 'sizeValue': '42', 'size': 'Euro Size', 'order': 3, 'prefix': 'EURO'}], 'sizeSellerData': [{'mrp': 6499, 'sellerPartnerId': 6206, 'availableCount': 121, 'sellableInventoryCount': 121, 'warehouses': ['106'], 'supplyType': 'ON_HAND', 'discountId': '11203218:23363948', 'discountedPrice': 2924}]}, {'skuId': 38724446, 'styleId': 11203218, 'action': '/product/11203218/related/9?co=1', 'label': '9', 'available': True, 'sizeType': 'UK Size', 'originalStyle': True, 'measurements': [{'type': 'Body Measurement', 'name': 'To Fit Foot Length', 'value': '27.1', 'minValue': '27.1', 'maxValue': '27.1', 'unit': 'cm', 'displayText': '27.1cm'}], 'allSizesList': [{'scaleCode': 'uk_size', 'sizeValue': '9', 'size': 'UK Size', 'order': 1, 'prefix': 'UK'}, {'scaleCode': 'us_size', 'sizeValue': '10', 'size': 'US Size', 'order': 2, 'prefix': 'US'}, {'scaleCode': 'euro_size', 'sizeValue': '43', 'size': 'Euro Size', 'order': 3, 'prefix': 'EURO'}], 'sizeSellerData': [{'mrp': 6499, 'sellerPartnerId': 6206, 'availableCount': 107, 'sellableInventoryCount': 107, 'warehouses': ['106'], 'supplyType': 'ON_HAND', 'discountId': '11203218:23363948', 'discountedPrice': 2924}]}, {'skuId': 38724448, 'styleId': 11203218, 'action': '/product/11203218/related/10?co=1', 'label': '10', 'available': True, 'sizeType': 'UK Size', 'originalStyle': True, 'measurements': [{'type': 'Body Measurement', 'name': 'To Fit Foot Length', 'value': '27.9', 'minValue': '27.9', 'maxValue': '27.9', 'unit': 'cm', 'displayText': '27.9cm'}], 'allSizesList': [{'scaleCode': 'uk_size', 'sizeValue': '10', 'size': 'UK Size', 'order': 1, 'prefix': 'UK'}, {'scaleCode': 'us_size', 'sizeValue': '11', 'size': 'US Size', 'order': 2, 'prefix': 'US'}, {'scaleCode': 'euro_size', 'sizeValue': '44.5', 'size': 'Euro Size', 'order': 3, 'prefix': 'EURO'}], 'sizeSellerData': [{'mrp': 6499, 'sellerPartnerId': 6206, 'availableCount': 112, 'sellableInventoryCount': 112, 'warehouses': ['106'], 'supplyType': 'ON_HAND', 'discountId': '11203218:23363948', 'discountedPrice': 2924}]}, {'skuId': 38724450, 'styleId': 11203218, 'action': '/product/11203218/related/11?co=1', 'label': '11', 'available': True, 'sizeType': 'UK Size', 'originalStyle': True, 'measurements': [{'type': 'Body Measurement', 'name': 'To Fit Foot Length', 'value': '28.8', 'minValue': '28.8', 'maxValue': '28.8', 'unit': 'cm', 'displayText': '28.8cm'}], 'allSizesList': [{'scaleCode': 'uk_size', 'sizeValue': '11', 'size': 'UK Size', 'order': 1, 'prefix': 'UK'}, {'scaleCode': 'us_size', 'sizeValue': '12', 'size': 'US Size', 'order': 2, 'prefix': 'US'}, {'scaleCode': 'euro_size', 'sizeValue': '46', 'size': 'Euro Size', 'order': 3, 'prefix': 'EURO'}], 'sizeSellerData': [{'mrp': 6499, 'sellerPartnerId': 6206, 'availableCount': 18, 'sellableInventoryCount': 18, 'warehouses': ['106'], 'supplyType': 'ON_HAND', 'discountId': '11203218:23363948', 'discountedPrice': 2924}]}, {'skuId': 38724452, 'styleId': 11203218, 'action': '/product/11203218/related/12?co=1', 'label': '12', 'available': False, 'sizeType': 'UK Size', 'originalStyle': True, 'measurements': [{'type': 'Body Measurement', 'name': 'To Fit Foot Length', 'value': '29.6', 'minValue': '29.6', 'maxValue': '29.6', 'unit': 'cm', 'displayText': '29.6cm'}], 'allSizesList': [{'scaleCode': 'uk_size', 'sizeValue': '12', 'size': 'UK Size', 'order': 1, 'prefix': 'UK'}, {'scaleCode': 'us_size', 'sizeValue': '13', 'size': 'US Size', 'order': 2, 'prefix': 'US'}, {'scaleCode': 'euro_size', 'sizeValue': '47', 'size': 'Euro Size', 'order': 3, 'prefix': 'EURO'}], 'sizeSellerData': []}], 'discounts': [{'type': 1, 'freeItem': False, 'label': '(55% OFF)', 'discountText': '', 'timerStart': '0', 'timerEnd': '1597084200', 'discountPercent': 55, 'offer': '', 'discountId': '11203218:23363948', 'heading': None, 'description': None, 'link': None, 'freeItemImage': None}], 'offers': [{'type': 'EMI', 'title': 'EMI option available', 'description': '', 'action': '/faqs', 'image': None}], 'bundledSkus': None, 'richPdp': None, 'landingPageUrl': 'sports-shoes/puma/puma-men-blue-hybrid-fuego-running-shoes/11203218/buy'}, 'pageName': 'Pdp', 'atsa': ['Sport', 'Material', 'Fastening', 'Ankle Height', 'Outsole Type', 'Cleats', 'Pronation for Running Shoes', 'Arch Type', 'Cushioning', 'Running Type', 'Warranty', 'Distance', 'Number of Components', 'Surface Type', 'Technology']}
```

Comment: html><head>
<title>Invalid URL</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Invalid URL</h1>
The requested URL "[no URL]", is invalid.<p>
Reference #9.be8d2c31.1596893409.a57d774
</p></body></html>

Comment: I am getting the same error. As I said in the question that when I run the MyntraScraperClass in MyntraScraper.py file it not return any error.

Comment: I think the problem is with some other component not the scraping part per se.

Comment: Yes, now you got my problem. From my point of view the requests package creating this problem.

Comment: But I don't understand how to solve this. The same code I try with URLLIB but it is not working for me.